Can't sort instanced splines
I have a curve object in which, through GN, I've called in a mesh object and instanced a curve line on each faces center. Now I want to be able to sort the instances clockwise beginning from one of them but I can't seem to accomplish this :(
I laid down a Sort Elements node and it just doesn't do what it's supposed to :(
Any help would be wildly appreciated.


Your circle is vertical, so you need to rotate your position around origin using either x or y axis and 90° angle. Then you can use such rotated position in the "Radial" texture, because it expects 2D coordinates (z=0). What you're doing currently is sampling a single value from the texture, so all weights are equal.

Could you elaborate a little more? I've already set the radial gradient to be along the positive X. What do I need to do specifically?

You use the "weights" on the sort node to define the position of each instance in the sort sequence.
So, for that purpose, the weights could be the angle around the center, which is given by arctan2 of the two components (I believe they're Y and Z in your case)

You can use additional math, such as:

multiply by -1 (or swap Y and Z) to invert the direction;
sum a constant angle (greater than pi) and use a floored modulo (by 2*pi) to displace the start point, etc.


Oh right,  that's simpler than rotating or  rearranging the coordinates to use gradient texture,  merry Xmas!
